# Accessing JSon substructure from the very first property in json.NET

Tags: f#, json.net

I have tried to find a similar answer but I can't. The problem I have is that I currently get a json that I have no control over that has a header property that has invalid characters in the property name. I basically just want to discard this property without using its name as I don't know the property name in advance either

I initialize a JObject like:

```
let jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json)
```

Json Example:

```
{
  "weird property name that I just want to discard": {
    "field1": "1234",
    "field2": "1234"
  }
}
```

What I would like is a JToken or JObject that represents the substructure after the first property

```
{
  "field1": "1234",
  "field2": "1234"
}
```

So that I can then start extracting my data from the json with the fieldnames field1 and field2 which I do know in advance.

I can achieve what I want by using

```
let fields = jsonObject.Children()
for field in fields do
  // extract information if it is the first iteration of the loop
```

But there has to be a better way...

Comment: You have the property name right there... `jsonObject.["weird property name that I just want to discard"]` It's not invalid, it's just another string.

Comment: I don't know the property name in advance. So I still need to extract the property name which I am struggling with as well.

Comment: Then get the first (or only) property value: `jsonObject.PropertyValues().Single()`

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I was looking for. I must have missed those methods when looking through the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeff mentioned in the comments I could achieve exactly what I wanted with

```
jsonObject.PropertyValues().Single()
```